# secure communication with the server - solution

Tags: ios, rest, mobile, ssl, oauth

I am currently facing problem with secure server communication. I am a mobile developer and I try to design REST (JSON output). To understand the problem let me show you a flow in my application:

1. First user login to the application
2. Then may download some personal information
3. When user moves in application i want to communicate with a server all the time.

So i figure that login & password will be send throught SSL (right? wrong? this is Question number one, maybe i should choose OAuth?), but then what? I receive login & password, store it into my Keychain, and any other services should be open for all users? I think this SSL in first request gime only semblance of security, not a real security.

Let me show you my REST so far:

### **Login:**

***request:***

`https://mywebsiteforrest.com/getin`

And there i put in header `username=root&password=pass`

***response:***

```
{
   "status":100, /*This status tell me that everything is OK */
   "userKey":"432fdsf732fds7fstsw87frd7s5fd",
   "timestamp":1378651048,
   "userId: 342
}
```

### **Later requests:**

***request:***

`https://mywebsiteforrest.com/getmydata`

And there i put in header `userId=342&key=432fdsf732fds7fstsw87frd7s5fd`

Or maybe i should ask for it that way:
`https://mywebsiteforrest.com/getmydata/342&key=432fdsf732fds7fstsw87frd7s5fd` ?

I am looking for advice is that secure or it is (like i said before) semblance of security. I know you hate that question, but - what is right way for doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I would advice using headers.

The headers are purely encrypted. The only information going over the network 'Plaintext' is related to the SSL setup and D/H (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) key exchange. This exchange is designed in a way not to yield any useful information to any third person or an unauthorized person and once it has taken place, all data is encrypted.